# PhoneGap library that helps with debugging AJAX requests

Tags: debugging, cordova

I have a simple PhoneGap project that makes a cross-domain AJAX request, but when the app runs on the device nothing happens.

Locally testing the app in Chrome it works fine.

I've tried the PhoneGap remote debugger, but it's very slow.

Is there a JavaScript library that I can include with my project that will assist me in debugging my app while it's on the device?

Comment: Have you whitelisted all the necessary domains in the PhoneGap config?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd try running it in the Chrome browser on an android device and use remote web inspector or checkout this post about how to use remote web inspector on iOS actually [right in PhoneGap](http://www.mobilexweb.com/blog/debugging-web-safari-phonegap-iphone-ipad)